# Get tweets from topics section with Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v1

I want to get tweets from a specific topic from the topics section. But I couldn't find this on the twitter api page or the tweepy website. how can I get this tweet with tweepy or twitter api?  Below picture shows the topics I followed. I need to select one topic from here and save these tweets for the project.

[Twitter topics example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHUs3.png)

Comment: I guess,  it is related the topic_ids , does anyone use it? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/spaces/lookup/api-reference/get-spaces-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build something like this, you would use *Tweet annotations*, which are a part of Twitter API v2 ([link to the official documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/annotations/overview)). These annotations are used inside Twitter to power the Topics features, but they may not always be a direct mapping.

Note that not all annotations are available via the API, as [mentioned in this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74094850/retrieve-viral-tweets-topic-from-twitter-api/74109739#74109739).

Let's take your example - you're looking at the Topics page showing what you are following. I also follow Augmented Reality, so I clicked through that link to a timeline of Tweets in that topic, and chose the an individual Tweet I saw, Tweet ID `1582925073509281792`. I tried to pick one without a lot of links and hashtags to keep the response shorter, otherwise there would be a lot more entity values returned.

Then I used the API to get that Tweet and the attached annotations (this is the basic HTTP version not a Tweepy or Python version):

`GET /2/tweets/1582925073509281792?tweet.fields=context_annotations,entities`

The result:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "entities": {
      "mentions": [
        {
          "start": 0,
          "end": 8,
          "username": "tipatat",
          "id": "94606087"
        }
      ]
    },
    "id": "1582925073509281792",
    "edit_history_tweet_ids": [
      "1582925073509281792"
    ],
    "text": "@tipatat AR is very much a part of the larger system we think of as the Metaverse…",
    "context_annotations": [
      {
        "domain": {
          "id": "46",
          "name": "Business Taxonomy",
          "description": "Categories within Brand Verticals that narrow down the scope of Brands"
        },
        "entity": {
          "id": "1557697333571112960",
          "name": "Technology Business",
          "description": "Brands, companies, advertisers and every non-person handle with the profit intent related to softwares, apps, communication equipments, hardwares"
        }
      },
      {
        "domain": {
          "id": "30",
          "name": "Entities [Entity Service]",
          "description": "Entity Service top level domain, every item that is in Entity Service should be in this domain"
        },
        "entity": {
          "id": "848920371311001600",
          "name": "Technology",
          "description": "Technology and computing"
        }
      },
      {
        "domain": {
          "id": "131",
          "name": "Unified Twitter Taxonomy",
          "description": "A taxonomy of user interests. "
        },
        "entity": {
          "id": "848920371311001600",
          "name": "Technology",
          "description": "Technology and computing"
        }
      },
      {
        "domain": {
          "id": "131",
          "name": "Unified Twitter Taxonomy",
          "description": "A taxonomy of user interests. "
        },
        "entity": {
          "id": "1427745203700469767",
          "name": "Metaverse"
        }
      },
      {
        "domain": {
          "id": "165",
          "name": "Technology",
          "description": "for individual and types of technology, e.g., food technology, 3D printing"
        },
        "entity": {
          "id": "848920371311001600",
          "name": "Technology",
          "description": "Technology and computing"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

That's still long set of responses, but we can start to find things we might be interested in from here. Each annotation has a top-level *domain* and then an individual *id* within that domain. If we look down the list we can see that domain `131` with entity id `1427745203700469767` seems to be about "Metaverse". Now we have a way to search for Tweets that Twitter has identified as related to "Metaverse"!

If we run a search using `context` of `131.1427745203700469767` (this is `domain_id.entity_id`) then we can get back some related Tweets. I'll add in the text `augmented reality` to narrow things down. Again I've just used the HTTP format here, you can modify this for the library of your choice.

`GET /2/tweets/search/recent?query=context:131.1427745203700469767 augmented reality`

That [call returns 10 Tweets](https://oauth-playground.glitch.me/?id=tweetsRecentSearch&params=%28%27query%21%27context%3A131.1427745203700469767%20augmented%20reality%27%29_) (by default) on the topic of Metaverse, in this case.

You will need to experiment with identifying usable context ids - not every topic is directly reflected by contexts in the API, and this will not exactly match what you might see on a particular tab in the Twitter app itself.

Here's a link to a useful post about how to do something similar: [How to search for Tweets about various 'Topics' using the Twitter API v2](https://dev.to/suhemparack/how-to-search-for-tweets-about-various-topics-using-the-twitter-api-v2-3p86). I also recommend using Twitter's [API tools](https://developer.twitter.com/apitools) and [API Playground](https://oauth-playground.glitch.me/?id=tweetsRecentSearch&params=%28%27query%21%27context%3A131.1427745203700469767+augmented+reality%27%29_) to test this out.